# Why are the Caps Lock and Num lock indicators not working on my keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

Recently I've upgraded my Ubuntu.

When I press the <kbd>Caps-Lock</kbd> its indicator on my keyboard turns on, but it doesn't turn off when I press it again!

And also I've got problem with <kbd>NumLock</kbd> key. When I press it, it's light indicator doesn't turn on but NumLock has actually been activated!

Is it a bug?

Comment: If you plug in another keyboard, can you change it by using the second one?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of the inappropriate driver used. Ubuntu's default drivers might not suite your keyboard. If You have a dual boot use the keyboard on windows to confirm it is because of Ubuntu only. If yes then you will have to try additional drivers that might be provided by Manufacturer or Download from Internet. There is a additional driver option for Ubuntu in the dash. Use it to solve your problem.